# Pack .arr inside in the apk in aosp build

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-build-flavors, android-make

In my project, I have one .aar file(Bundle of .so files which build on armebabi-v7a) and it will successfully build in the Android AOSP source tree. (Source tree is based on the arm64-v8a).

But I run the application, in the device, it will crash and shows the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

Please help me to solve the below issue, 
To pack .aar lib in the application apk itself.

Comment: build the apk with .arr file using android studio and install it on your device first. if it works fine then add it into the source as pre-built apk

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I already did this method. I want to build all my source within AOSP source tree.